# Custom metric not showing up on New Relic

Tags: go, newrelic, newrelic-platform

I am using the Go's port of newrelic SDK to create custom metric in NR. I was able to create a  new metric for measuring throughput for my app and I am trying to create a metric for average response time.

I have added the necessary code to report the (average response time) data but I do not see it showing up in my new relic when I am trying to create a new graph (The metric does not recognize the custom metric name). However, if I change the GUID (which forces NR to create a new plugin entry), I am able to see the custom metric name in auto complete. I switched back to the old GUID and still I do not see the new custom metric name.

I can always delete the old New Relic Plugin and create a new one with a new GUID but is this really necessary???

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [GoRelic](https://github.com/yvasiyarov/gorelic) try clearing the metric data from the New Relic dashboard:

- Go to the drop down menu in the top right corner (near your username).
- Click on "Account Settings".
- Go to the "Connected agents" tab.
- Click the red "Clear metric data" button on the right.

That should wipe any stored measurements from your app and *may* cause it to refresh the metric labels again.

Answer (score 0):

Are you attempting to put your Plugin metrics on a Custom Dashboard? https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/dashboards-menu/custom-dashboards

Or, are you attempting to use the new Agent SDK to monitor your Go app? 
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/features/agent-sdk
https://github.com/yvasiyarov/newrelic_go_api